# EJB 3.1 Unit Test, two Beans, one @DependsOn the other, exchange through mock

Tags: java, unit-testing, jakarta-ee, mocking, ejb

I currently working on my first EJB project with Glassfish 3.1.2.2. I have two beans:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class ABean implements AInterface {
//implementation
}
```

and

```
@DependsOn("ABean")
@Startup
@Singleton
@EJB(name = "ABean", beaninterface = AInterface)
public class BBean implements BInterface {
//implementation
}
```

I want to unit test the "BBean" and mock the "ABean". Currently, when I'm starting the JUnitTest the "ABean" will be started but **is there a way to exchange the "ABean" with a "ABeanMock"?**

I need a automatic mechanism to exchange the implementation with the mock as these tests will be run on a jenkins server. So a manual adoption of the code is ok for single manual test but cannot be made for automatic testing.

I'm using the Glassfish Embedded API for unit tests.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/) for this.

[Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/guides/) runs your tests inside a container, deploying to an application server if necessary. You can choose to use selected classes only, so this would allow you to create a replacement `ABean` that implements `AInterface`, and choose not to deploy the *real* `ABean` - which would result in your replacement being used instead.

The test would look something like this:

```
@Singleton(name = "ABean")
class AMockBean implements AInterface {
  // Mocked bean implementation
}

@RunsWith(Arquillian.class)
public class MyTests {

  @Inject
  private BBean bbean;

  @Deployment
  public Archive<?> deployment() {
     return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)
            .addClass(BBean.class)
            .addClass(AMockBean.class)
            .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
  }

  @Test
  public void testBBean() {
    bbean.whatever();
  }
}
```

This is all untested, but it should be something along the lines of this. Depending on your environment and dependencies, it might be more difficult to configure correctly.

Arquillian is a wonderful tool, but it can be difficult to set up exactly the way you want it when starting out. Luckily there are [several guides](http://arquillian.org/guides/) to help you through the process.